# Pidgin: cannot send messages or set topics in chats via dbus

Tags: dbus, pidgin, libpurple

I would like to send messages to Pidgin chats or set chat topics via dbus. Following [this guide](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/DbusHowto) I was able to write some pretty straightforward code to do just that, and it does indeed result in messages appearing or chat topics being changed... but it only seems to affect my window, without the other participants being aware of any messages or topic changes.

I'm using

```
purple.PurpleConvChatSetTopic(chat_data, user, topic)
```

and

```
purple.PurpleConvChatWrite(chat_data, user, message, flag, time)
```

I don't think this is due to any misuse of the dbus api as the calls actually result in actions. I just wonder if I need to perform some sort of authentication first? Or maybe the user can only be the current user? I tried with my nick and also setting it as unicode but to no avail.

Here is the complete code anyway:

```
import dbus
import time
# define chat_name, user, topic, message
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
obj = bus.get_object('im.pidgin.purple.PurpleService', '/im/pidgin/purple/PurpleObject')
purple = dbus.Interface(obj, 'im.pidgin.purple.PurpleInterface')
for p in purple.PurpleGetConversations():
  if purple.PurpleConversationGetName(p) == chat_name:
    chat = p
chat_data = purple.PurpleConversationGetChatData(chat)
purple.PurpleConvChatSetTopic(chat_data, user, topic)
purple.PurpleConvChatWrite(chat_data, user, message, 0, int(time.time()))
```